# port SYCL/DPC++ code originally written for GPUs to FPGAs

Tags: intel, intel-fpga, intel-oneapi, sycl, dpc++

I'm kinda new to the world of FPGAs and I'm trying to port some code written for GPUs to FPGAs, to compare the performances.

From my understanding, using `parallel_for` ain't a good practice (in fact it runs very slow), instead (I think) I should use a `single_task` and an unrolled for loop. I'm struggling to make it work properly though.

So, I have

```
q.submit([&](sycl::handler &h){
   h.parallel_for<class Foo>(sycl::nd_range<1>(n_blocks * n_threads, n_threads),
          [=](auto& it) {
              some_kernel(it, <other params here ...> );
          });
}).wait();
```

and my attempt is

```
q.submit([&](sycl::handler &h){
   h.single_task<class Foo>(
     #pragma unroll
     for(int i = 0; i < n_blocks * n_threads; ++i)
        some_kernel(...)
   );
}).wait();
```

But I'm not sure how to adapt what I was previously doing with a `sycl::item` (for instance, how to use the loop index to replace the calls to the methods `get_group`, `get_local_id`? ).

Should I entirely change the design of the kernel ? In other word, is the "work_groups - work_group_size" approach not appropriate with FPGAs ?